Launching Node project through NX console prevents VScode debugging
I have a basic web project where I launch my simulation with NX console by going to the "Big N" in the left menu in Visual Studio Code, serve, development, and clicking the play button. This causes the server to start on the local host port 3000. If the simulator is not running, then I can set breakpoints in my typescript code. However, when the simulator does run, and I try to set a break point I get an "unbound breakpoint" that is gray. I've read many SO threads about this which all point to setting sourceMaps, this doesnt work for me possibly because of using NX console to launch the simulation. I've already tried restarting VScode and clicking F5.
Note I am able to debug through chrome
Launch.json
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
   {
     "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
     "type": "chrome",
     "request": "launch",
     "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
     "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
     "sourceMaps": true,
     "trace": true
   }
 ]
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc/tools",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "importHelpers": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}


